# Website suddenly went down, Ubuntu / Apache server is still up

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

I got an email alert from the monitoring service I use, UptimeRobot about my site being down. The site is https://vendbits.com

In the Chrome web browser, I see the error message:

This site can’t be reached
`vendbits.com` took too long to respond.

I'm able to login to the server via SSH fine.

When I run `service  --status-all` in terminal, I get:

```
 [ - ]  apache-htcacheclean
 [ + ]  apache2
 [ + ]  apparmor
 [ + ]  apport
 [ + ]  atd
 [ - ]  console-setup.sh
 [ + ]  cron
 [ - ]  cryptdisks
 [ - ]  cryptdisks-early
 [ + ]  dbus
 [ + ]  fail2ban
 [ - ]  grub-common
 [ - ]  hwclock.sh
 [ - ]  irqbalance
 [ - ]  iscsid
 [ + ]  kdump-tools
 [ + ]  kexec
 [ + ]  kexec-load
 [ - ]  keyboard-setup.sh
 [ + ]  kmod
 [ - ]  lvm2
 [ - ]  lvm2-lvmpolld
 [ + ]  multipath-tools
 [ + ]  mysql
 [ - ]  open-iscsi
 [ - ]  open-vm-tools
 [ - ]  plymouth
 [ - ]  plymouth-log
 [ + ]  postfix
 [ + ]  procps
 [ - ]  rsync
 [ + ]  rsyslog
 [ - ]  screen-cleanup
 [ + ]  ssh
 [ + ]  udev
 [ + ]  ufw
 [ + ]  unattended-upgrades
 [ - ]  uuidd
 [ - ]  x11-common
```

Which all seems normal, I suppose?

I updated and upgraded all packages using:

`sudo apt update` & `sudo apt upgrade`

I checked the logs in `/var/log/syslog/` and the most recent entries are cron jobs executing:

```
Jul 20 02:35:01 vendbits CRON[60039]: (root) CMD (wget -O - https://vendbits.com/XXX >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jul 20 02:35:01 vendbits CRON[60041]: (root) CMD (wget -O - https://vendbits.com/XXX >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jul 20 02:35:01 vendbits CRON[60040]: (root) CMD (wget -O - https://vendbits.com/XXX >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jul 20 02:35:01 vendbits CRON[60042]: (root) CMD (wget -O - https://vendbits.com/XXX >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jul 20 02:35:01 vendbits CRON[60043]: (root) CMD (wget -O - https://vendbits.com/XXX >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jul 20 02:35:01 vendbits CRON[60047]: (root) CMD (wget -O - https://vendbits.com/admin/updateCryptoPrices >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jul 20 02:39:01 vendbits CRON[60053]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
Jul 20 02:39:22 vendbits systemd[1]: Starting Clean php session files...
Jul 20 02:39:23 vendbits sessionclean[60092]: PHP Warning:  Module "exif" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
Jul 20 02:39:23 vendbits sessionclean[60092]: PHP Warning:  Module "fileinfo" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
Jul 20 02:39:23 vendbits sessionclean[60092]: PHP Warning:  Module "gd" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
Jul 20 02:39:23 vendbits sessionclean[60092]: PHP Warning:  Module "imagick" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
Jul 20 02:39:23 vendbits sessionclean[60092]: PHP Warning:  Module "mbstring" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
Jul 20 02:39:23 vendbits systemd[1]: phpsessionclean.service: Succeeded.
Jul 20 02:39:23 vendbits systemd[1]: Finished Clean php session files.
Jul 20 02:40:01 vendbits CRON[60150]: (root) CMD (wget -O - URL-REMOVED >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jul 20 02:40:01 vendbits CRON[60151]: (root) CMD (wget -O - URL-REMOVED >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jul 20 02:40:01 vendbits CRON[60152]: (root) CMD (wget -O - URL-REMOVED >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jul 20 02:40:01 vendbits CRON[60153]: (root) CMD (wget -O - URL-REMOVED >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jul 20 02:40:01 vendbits CRON[60154]: (root) CMD (wget -O - URL-REMOVED >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jul 20 02:40:01 vendbits CRON[60160]: (root) CMD (wget -O - URL-REMOVED >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jul 20 02:45:01 vendbits CRON[60203]: (root) CMD (wget -O - URL-REMOVED >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jul 20 02:45:01 vendbits CRON[60202]: (root) CMD (wget -O - URL-REMOVED >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jul 20 02:45:01 vendbits CRON[60204]: (root) CMD (wget -O - URL-REMOVED >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jul 20 02:45:01 vendbits CRON[60205]: (root) CMD (wget -O - URL-REMOVED >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jul 20 02:45:01 vendbits CRON[60206]: (root) CMD (wget -O - URL-REMOVED >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jul 20 02:45:01 vendbits CRON[60210]: (root) CMD (wget -O - URL-REMOVED >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jul 20 02:50:01 vendbits CRON[60559]: (root) CMD (wget -O - URL-REMOVED >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jul 20 02:50:01 vendbits CRON[60560]: (root) CMD (wget -O - URL-REMOVED >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jul 20 02:50:01 vendbits CRON[60561]: (root) CMD (wget -O - URL-REMOVED >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jul 20 02:50:01 vendbits CRON[60562]: (root) CMD (wget -O - URL-REMOVED >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jul 20 02:50:01 vendbits CRON[60563]: (root) CMD (wget -O - URL-REMOVED >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jul 20 02:50:01 vendbits CRON[60567]: (root) CMD (wget -O - URL-REMOVED >/dev/null 2>&1)
```

I checked disk space using `df`

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev              899424        0    899424   0% /dev
tmpfs             183388      992    182396   1% /run
/dev/vda1       50620216 12721684  37882148  26% /
tmpfs             916932        0    916932   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs             916932        0    916932   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0         69504    69504         0 100% /snap/lxd/22753
/dev/loop3         63488    63488         0 100% /snap/core20/1494
/dev/loop1         69632    69632         0 100% /snap/lxd/22526
/dev/loop2         56960    56960         0 100% /snap/core18/2538
/dev/loop4         56960    56960         0 100% /snap/core18/2409
/dev/loop6         48128    48128         0 100% /snap/snapd/16292
/dev/loop5         63488    63488         0 100% /snap/core20/1518
/dev/vda15        106858     5321    101537   5% /boot/efi
/dev/loop7         48128    48128         0 100% /snap/snapd/16010
tmpfs             183384        0    183384   0% /run/user/0
```

All that seems normal.

I check apache error logs `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

```
[Wed Jul 20 00:00:03.106315 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1313657] AH00163: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1f configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jul 20 00:00:03.106349 2022] [core:notice] [pid 1313657] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Jul 20 00:39:42.145217 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1313657] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
PHP Warning:  Module "exif" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module "fileinfo" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module "gd" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module "imagick" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module "mbstring" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[Wed Jul 20 00:39:59.186682 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 838] AH00163: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1f configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jul 20 00:39:59.186762 2022] [core:notice] [pid 838] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Jul 20 01:11:10.282503 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 838] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
PHP Warning:  Module "exif" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module "fileinfo" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module "gd" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module "imagick" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module "mbstring" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[Wed Jul 20 01:11:26.156646 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 837] AH00163: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1f configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jul 20 01:11:26.156734 2022] [core:notice] [pid 837] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Jul 20 01:23:47.910850 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 837] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
PHP Warning:  Module "exif" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module "fileinfo" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module "gd" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module "imagick" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module "mbstring" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[Wed Jul 20 01:23:48.120158 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2329] AH00163: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1f configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jul 20 01:23:48.120259 2022] [core:notice] [pid 2329] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

According to serverfault post

> "these are not errors, they are just informational notices. error.log is misnamed; much of what goes to it is informational only. – ysth May 21, 2015 at 17:25"

`/var/log/apache2/access.log` latest entries are the same cron jobs as in `/var/log/syslog/`

```
137.184.142.4 - - [20/Jul/2022:03:10:02 +0000] "GET /XXX-URL-HIDDEN HTTP/1.1" 200 6384 "-" "Wget/1.20.3 (linux-gnu)"
137.184.142.4 - - [20/Jul/2022:03:10:02 +0000] "GET /XXX-URL-HIDDEN  HTTP/1.1" 200 7424 "-" "Wget/1.20.3 (linux-gnu)"
137.184.142.4 - - [20/Jul/2022:03:10:02 +0000] "GET /XXX-URL-HIDDEN  HTTP/1.1" 200 6449 "-" "Wget/1.20.3 (linux-gnu)"
137.184.142.4 - - [20/Jul/2022:03:15:01 +0000] "GET /URL-HIDDEN  HTTP/1.1" 200 6384 "-" "Wget/1.20.3 (linux-gnu)"
137.184.142.4 - - [20/Jul/2022:03:15:01 +0000] "GET /URL-HIDDEN  HTTP/1.1" 200 7424 "-" "Wget/1.20.3 (linux-gnu)"
137.184.142.4 - - [20/Jul/2022:03:15:01 +0000] "GET /URL-HIDDEN  HTTP/1.1" 200 6384 "-" "Wget/1.20.3 (linux-gnu)"
137.184.142.4 - - [20/Jul/2022:03:15:01 +0000] "GET /URL-HIDDEN  HTTP/1.1" 200 7427 "-" "Wget/1.20.3 (linux-gnu)"
137.184.142.4 - - [20/Jul/2022:03:15:01 +0000] "GET /URL-HIDDEN  HTTP/1.1" 200 6384 "-" "Wget/1.20.3 (linux-gnu)"
137.184.142.4 - - [20/Jul/2022:03:15:01 +0000] "GET /URL-HIDDEN  HTTP/1.1" 200 6449 "-" "Wget/1.20.3 (linux-gnu)"
::1 - - [20/Jul/2022:03:15:02 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1f (internal dummy connection)"
137.184.142.4 - - [20/Jul/2022:03:20:01 +0000] "GET /URL-HIDDEN  HTTP/1.1" 200 7424 "-" "Wget/1.20.3 (linux-gnu)"
137.184.142.4 - - [20/Jul/2022:03:20:01 +0000] "GET /URL-HIDDEN  HTTP/1.1" 200 6384 "-" "Wget/1.20.3 (linux-gnu)"
137.184.142.4 - - [20/Jul/2022:03:20:01 +0000] "GET /URL-HIDDEN  HTTP/1.1" 200 6384 "-" "Wget/1.20.3 (linux-gnu)"
137.184.142.4 - - [20/Jul/2022:03:20:01 +0000] "GET /URL-HIDDEN  HTTP/1.1" 200 7427 "-" "Wget/1.20.3 (linux-gnu)"
137.184.142.4 - - [20/Jul/2022:03:20:01 +0000] "GET /URL-HIDDEN  HTTP/1.1" 200 6384 "-" "Wget/1.20.3 (linux-gnu)"
137.184.142.4 - - [20/Jul/2022:03:20:01 +0000] "GET /URL-HIDDEN  HTTP/1.1" 200 6449 "-" "Wget/1.20.3 (linux-gnu)"
```

The domain registration was renewed last month.

What else should I be checking?

The only other thing I could think of is somebody created a listing (vendbits is a marketplace for digital products) for a pirated version of FL studio, and I received a message through the privacyguardian email system 6 days ago for a listing removal request. The site only receives about 2 visitors a day since it's new and I didn't get around to removing the listing. Was the domain blacklisted through ICANN or something?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A timeout usually points toward a firewall issue.

Comment: It appears the firewall was already inactive since it reads ```Status: inactive``` when using ```sudo ufw status``` I'm not sure what's going on since I wasn't even on my workstation when the site went down.

Comment: Your hoster most probably has a firewall as well.

Comment: I'm hosted at digitalocean, and they usually give notice if there's any type of maintenance performed. How feasible is it that the domain was blacklisted/seized for the piracy listing? The site was launched recently and has very little traffic and the takedown request was sent only 6 days ago, so it's hard to believe that's the reason, right?

Comment: Well, if the owner of a site does not react on a takedown notice the next step would be to have the hoster take the site down. But they should notify you about it. One way or the other, you should just contact your hoster and ask.

Comment: I posted the same question on digitalocean forum https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/website-suddenly-went-down-ubuntu-apache-server-is-still-up and still have not received a reply. The site has been down for nearly 20 hours now. How can I resolve this??

Comment: Why do you post on community forums? You are a paying customer. Contact their support.

Comment: DigitalOcean had a little unread message for me regarding the DMCA complaint in the ticket system. I should have it resolved shortly. Thank you very much for the help, Gerald.